# Google Cloud Build fails due to missing CMake

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cmake, gcloud

I am trying to deploy a Flask/ML app to Google Cloud but encountering this issue;

When I try to run `gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/project-name/index` with a requirements.txt file, it throws **CMake must be installed to build dlib**. Since now, I didn't have any problems working with dlib (I have cmake and build-essential already installed) and when I connect Google Cloud Shell via ssh, I can see both build-essential and cmake is installed and up to date on there too.

I tried to build on Ubuntu and Windows machines, same error consists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! CMake needs to be built in Dockerfile, not locally or in cloud shell.

Adding `RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install cmake` before `RUN pip install -r requirements.txt` in Dockerfile resolved the issue.